# Styled Components + React: CSS transition keeps resetting

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a styled component:

```
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const slideToCorner = keyframes`
  from {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  to {
    right: 300px;
    top: 50px;
  }
`;

const SlideToCorner = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  ${props => props.slide && `animation: ${slideToCorner} 0.5s linear;`}
  transition: all 1s linear;
`;

export default SlideToCorner;
```

This is how it's being used:

```
<SlideToCorner slide={matchingStatus === MATCHING_STATES.CONFIRMING}>
  <TargetBox>
    <LocalVideo />
  </TargetBox>
</SlideToCorner>
```

However, when it animates it keeps resetting back to it's original position halfway through the animation:

[image]

I can confirm that it is not the `matchingStatus === MATCHING_STATES.CONFIRMING` that is causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `forwards` in

`animation: ${slideToCorner} 0.5s linear forwards`

Or use `animation-fill-mode: forwards`

Check the `animation-fill-mode` property for different behaviors

Comment: woahhhhhh it worked!! i've never seen animation-fill-mode